# Naming conventions в c++

Tags: c++

Так как в c++ нет устоявшегося соглашения по поводу именования различных сущностей, то каждый выбирает свой способ. Однако всегда следует использовать один и тот же способ именования во всем проекте.

Однако мой вопрос таков: если я пишу код, который придётся поддерживать не только мне, то как быть с подключаемыми библиотеками? Если я подключаю, к примеру, `box2d`, в котором классы начинаются с приставки `b2`, а методы все с большой буквы, в то время как я предпочитаю `java`-стиль - классы с большой, методы с маленькой, то как в таком случае быть?

Если это игровой движок, и я хочу, чтобы классы физики были не внутренними, а видны пользователю? Дурной ли это тон - использовать в проекте библиотеки с другими naming conventions. И как тогда быть? Использовать `typedef`? И как тогда быть с функциями?

Что думаете по этому поводу? Как сами поступаете в таких случаях?

Comment: Как говорил О. Бендер, отбирая огурец у Паниковского - "Не делайте из еды культа!" Все хорошо в меру, и делать культ из именования вплоть до того, чтоб переименовывать сторонние библиотеки - на мой взгляд, перебор. ИМХО, конечно ("имею мнение - хрен оспоришь!" :))

Comment: Ну и конечно, отказываться от библиотеки, потому что у нее другое naming convention, тоже слегка перебор.

Comment: @Harry Угу, вы правы. Просто иногда включается режим идеалиста, и миксы различных методов именования в одном проекте начинают резать глаза)

Comment: Если здесь не ответят и закроют вопрос, на [**Software Engineering**](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) попробуйте спросить. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**режим сарказка** Проблем с наименованием методов в с++ у Вас не может возникнуть:) в с++ нет методов:) **режим сарказма выключен**

Когда возникает проблема наименования на стыке двух проектов (или библиотека и проект), то никто не мешает написать ещё один слой абстракции, который скроет за собой все неудобные вещи, в том числе имена.

Но если хочется пользователю отдавать внутренние имена - то это сама по себе проблема. Отдавайте только свои обертки. Если в будущем ремята с box2d сделают что то страшное (например, какую то функцию решат удалить или поменяют сигнатуру функции), то Ваш код не сломается - нужно будет только обертку доделать. Если же пользователю дать свободу - нужно будет переделывать много кода.

Comment: Обертки - самое первое, что идёт в голову, это да. Но вот писать их так лень... Но мой внутренний перфекционист все равно решил, что я буду это делать. А что касается методов и функций - кто-то отождествляет эти понятия, кто-то считает разными. Лично я считаю функцию чем-то больше математическим. Нечто, что при неизменных данных на входе вернет тот же ответ. А методы - все остальное.

Comment: узнайте о том, что такое *pure function*.

Comment: прекрасно знаю, что это такое. Но спорить из-за не совсем однозначных терминов "функция" и "метод" нет смысла, тем более, что вопрос был не о том) пока что не буду отмечать ответ, может кто-то ещё напишет что-то интересное

Comment: еще раз читайте комментарий от   Harry... Лично я могу только это сказать

Comment: вот даже напишешь пометку "сарказм", все равно юмор не просечут. Да, можно функции хоть вычислителями называть. Главное, чтобы коллеги понимали.

Comment: @KoVadim хех, есть разные уровни сарказма, не знал, какой из них был использован)

Comment: вспомнилось - у всех программистов есть три проблемы - придумывание имен и ошибка на единицу.

Comment: @KoVadim, хах, на просторах интернета встречал такую разновидность этой фразы: "В программировании существует лишь два характерных затруднения: инвалидация кеша, наименование сущностей и ошибка на единицу".

Comment: да, это второй вариант этой шутки.